# How to remove paragraph spacing for title page

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment, titles

I am writing a lab report and have formated my document to have space in between paragraphs. Is there a way to remove the spacing between my affiliation and the date of submission as seen below, but to keep the spacing for all other paragraphs?:

[image]

Here is the relevant part of the latex code:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\topskip}{1em}

\title{N-Body Simulation of the formation of a Globular Cluster} 
\author{O.L.C. Moore}
\affiliation{\normalfont Level 3 computing Project, Group C1}
\date{Submitted: \today{}, Date of Experiment: 2021}
```

Comment: This would be dependent on `\maketitle`, which would be defined within the class. What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{revtex4} is currently what I have in my document, although I am unsure what the revtex4 does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me and the `revtex4-2` class. Try with yours.
[image: a]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{revtex4-2}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\topskip}{1em}

\begin{document}
\title{N-Body Simulation of the formation of a Globular Cluster} 
\author{O.L.C. Moore}
\affiliation{\normalfont Level 3 computing Project, Group C1 \vspace*{-20pt}} % negative space
\date{Submitted: \today{}, Date of Experiment: 2021}
    
\maketitle
    
\end{document}
```

Or perhaps it is better, to keep the style, with

```
\affiliation{\normalfont Level 3 computing Project, Group C1 \vspace*{-1em}} % negative space
```